# Best way of deployment automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, deployment, devops, github-actions

I've made a pretty simple web application which has a REST API backend service written in `Python/Django` and a FE service written in `JS/React`. Both parts are containerized and can be launched locally via docker-compose. They are situated in separate github repositories, and every time a new tag is pushed to the corresponding repo, an image is built and pushed to the corresponding `ecr` repo via `github actions`. Until that point everything works smoothly, but the problem is that, I don't know how to properly automate the deployment process to the test and production environments. The goal is to have those environments as similar as possible.

My current solution for test env is to simply upload docker-compose file to the ec2 instance via github actions, then manually run the docker-compose command, which pulls images from ecr.

Even though it's a simple solution, it's not very scalable or automated and requires some work to be done in order to update an application. The desired flow is to have a manual GitHub action in each repository, which would deploy either BE or FE to the test or prod environment without any need to ssh into the server and do any other manipulations with docker.

I was looking at ECS, but it seems that it's a solution for bigger apps, which need several or more instances to run. I want my app to be used by many users, but I'm not sure, when it will happen. So maybe i should stick to something less complicated than ECS. Are there any simpler solutions, which i am missing? Like Elastic beanstack or something from any other provider?

I will be happy to receive a feedback on anything I wrote in this post, thanks!